# How to monitor a service using monit for cpu % metrics.?

Tags: monit

I have used monit to monitor various services which were offered by monit itself but I am unable to monitor the custom service which is not generating its PID file.

I want if a particular service is using 90% of CPU then It should restart the service with a custom command I pass.

Also, let me know if is there another tool to achieve this.

Comment: If you really want i can write a script that can do this, but why not to ask how to fix the service?

Comment: I want it to watch the particular service so that it can watch it continuously. Also, Fixing up the app is out of our scope.

Answer (score 0):

I have created my custom script which monitors the particular process using top and alerts me when it reaches the threshold. I am running this script in the background.

Comment: Is it possible to share the script.

Comment: @Hussain7 This question was posted 6 months back. I have created and scrap that script because we moved to "Datadog" for process monitoring.